# Back button affected by FormClosing event

Tags: c#

I want to go back to the form1 but everytime I click the back button, it triggers the FormClosing event so it prompts me if I want to quit the application. How can I solve this problem in order to exclude the other buttons from the FormClosing event?

```
private void Form2_FormClosing_1(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to quit?", "Exit",
     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
private void back_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();  
}
```

Comment: Check the FormClosingEventArgs parameter. There is a Reason property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing to do would be to set global variable that will tell closing event to show/not show that dialog.

Try something along these lines.

```
private bool CalledFromButton = false;    
private void Form2_FormClosing_1(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(CalledFromButton)
           return;
        DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to quit?", "Exit",
         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
    private void back_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CalledFromButton = true;
        this.Hide();  
    }
```